# i am trying to make a batch script which help me to format my pc and create one backup file for me too. How I am able to make it

Tags: python, c#, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script to format my pc and create a backup file for me while the formating process starts . How i am able to make such type of batch script please help me guys

Comment: Add your code here to help you.  @Tech with Md

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: You've listed three language tags. Please limit to only one, preferably the one where you have code already.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't & It's not advisable to run these kind of scripts in you cmd/Powershell....

It's completely waste of time...Even though if we build such scripts, We have to make that script such that it has to bypass all the permissions...After lot effort even though once we managed to build it...It wont work on different systems...Because a whole new permissions has to be bypassed manually..So it's not advisable to make such scripts run on PC

Answer (score -1):

You can't format a PC, but you can format a disk using format command. And for backup you can copy files to a folder or a disk using xcopy.

Comment: Format a disk guess the is not the topic about the `OP` asked about

Answer (score -1):

You should first create and run one script, before the process start, 'cause u could potencially overlap the time that the OS need to prepare the process, that saves you work, files, statuses... etc

Write another one that it's able to read and execute this one.

Then you can upload them (or write the process to autoupload it in the script) to save both in any cloud based solution.

Finally, when the PC is restored, you just need to download it one from the cloud, and it should be able to download the another one and run it, restablishing your previous status.